# Tapered/sloped text effect in Illustrator (NOT skew or perspective)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path, transform

I'm not too sure how to describe the effect that I'm going for or what it is even called.  Thus, I'm having some trouble finding any help through Google.

I want to accomplish something like this "SLOPED" text below, but have the bottoms of the letters follow the slope as well instead of being horizontal.

[image: Sloped Text Demo]

I have tried using the free transform tool, skewing, and using perspective, but I don't like the effect they are resulting in.  All of the tools that I just mentioned result in the appearance of the word being angled away from the viewer (perspective).  I want more of this style effect, whereas the letters are not skewed horizontally, but scaled evenly along a path that I lay out.

What is the name of this text effect?  Can anyone point me in the right direction to a tutorial or know how to accomplish this themselves?

I know that I could go through and do this letter by letter, but I was really hoping to find an easier method.

**EDIT**
I have removed many elements of my design and quickly threw some sample text in it, but this should give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish.  I want a mixture of the above and below effects.

[image: Slope Demo 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it in the following way:

Type any text lowering the letter size after every letter (I dont aware about any other way to do that) -

[image]

Expand and ungroup,

Press [image]

That's what I got -

[image]

---

Another options  is -

[image]

---

Third options  -

[image]

Comment: Yea, I knew I could do it manually that way, I was just hoping there was an easier way.  My actual path is also slightly different than that demo picture that I found online.  I'll edit my question to include a screen shot of what I am actually working on to clarify.  Thanks for the response though :)

Comment: @JohnManly ok, no problem, I leave this simple answer as is for anyone in future having similar Q

Comment: Updated my question.  If you have any further input or ideas as so how to accomplish this, I'm still all ear--eyes.

Comment: @JohnManly Please take a look of the addition to the answer

Comment: That's how I did it in my demo.  It's VERY close to what I have in my mind, but I don't like the way the text has the perspective effect.  I want it more like the first version you did.  The letters just scale along the paths as opposed to being skewed.  Maybe I'm just going to have to do this manually.  I don't think there is an easy way.  I was just hoping there was.

Comment: I think, using that last picture you posted and some tweaking, I'll get just what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm unaware of an automated way to keep the type perpendicular to the page and have it slope the way you are depicting. It must be done manually.

@Ilan has laid out the primary automated options there are.

There is one more option though, **Type on a path** with the varied type sizes.

[image]

I simply set the type on a straight horizontal path and used `Type > Type on a Path > Type on a Path Options` to align to **Ascender**. Then adjusted the point size of the characters. Note I also added a bit of baseline shift to the characters so they remained aligned at the top.

[image]

This keeps the type live so it can be edited, but you still need to adjust each character as necessary.

Comment: Yea, I knew I could go about this several ways manually.  I was already aware of the methods that @Ilan and yourself laid out, but I appreciate you both assisting me.  I was really hoping that there was a less labor intensive way of achieving this, especially because I have two lines of text that don't have perfectly horizontal top or bottom paths.  I guess I'll just have to do this the hard way.  Thanks!

Comment: The align to Ascender thing is news to me though, thanks for that!  I'm going to mark his answer as the accepted one though, since he was first.  Thanks again!

Comment: So.. you'll use my solution but mark the other answer correct? m'kay :)

Comment: Nah, I actually used a combination of the text warping options, the free transform tool, and manual manipulation of the paths.  I was just saying that I hadn't heard of the align: Ascender tip before.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to use the type on a path tool.

- Make the type path at the angle you want the text to rise.
- Once you have your text laid out, right click and use the shear tool to get
  the text back up straight again.

You'll have to just trial/error to get the right degree for the text to appear straight, but in the end, you'll have text that is upright, while going up/down at an angle.

Comment: There's no need to do it this way with type on a path, check Scott's answer.