# Text on a Path - Have Font Going from Big to Small

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create some text on a path that gets smaller as it goes down the path. Similar to the text that says "Steam & Printer Job Label" in the picture below.

I've tried some of the effects and object -> envelope effect but I can't get it to work?

Is there a way to do this rather the creating an outline of the text and manually resizing each letter?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: I think you may find your answer here: ["Tapered/sloped text effect in Illustrator (NOT skew or perspective)"](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/35984/8708)

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to do the trick.  Really surprised their isn't an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create path you want the text like.
2. write text you want.
3. right click on path > Arrange > Bring to Front
4. Select path and text together.
5. Select Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object.
   And you can follow this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KPHYfDVq_0). 
   I am not English native.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It kinda worked out but the text is being distorted in a weird way. Tried playing around with some options but no success. Here's what it looks [like](http://imgur.com/9wKhLzE).

Comment: You should rotate it. Look at [Sample](https://imgur.com/T3N0OZJ).

Comment: Didn't work but thanks for trying.  Ended up using this [solution](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35984/tapered-sloped-text-effect-in-illustrator-not-skew-or-perspective)