# how do I stop perspectival alterations to Distort function in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, distort

[image]Hello - this problem is causing me untold headaches as I just cant solve how to stop 'perspective' being added (which I specifically don't want). I want to distort some text (imagine its the word 'TEXT'), so that the letters are taller on the left hand side and shorter on the right hand side. In the normal way, its recommended to transform the text into a shape so that it remains vectorized and keeps its quality, and then simply to Edit / Transform path / distort. However, when I do this, distort adds an unwanted perspective which makes the smaller letters thinner and the larger letters fatter whilst altering the spacing. I only want to change the height from left to right. I don't want any perspective effects. I want all the letters to remain the same width and look like they are lying in the same plane rather than disappearing off into some perspectival hell. This, after all, makes the final letters almost illegible. Simple distort without perspective. How do I do it?

I include an image that shows what I want to do.

Comment: I was trying to do the same exact thing.  The answers on this question might help you [Tapered/sloped text effect in Illustrator (NOT skew or perspective)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35984/tapered-sloped-text-effect-in-illustrator-not-skew-or-perspective) It's an Illustrator question, but some of the techniques might work in PS

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I ended up using Illustrator in the end. The article you shared was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried playing around with the **Type > Warp Text...** feature yet? It's not perfect, but you might be able to get something close.

If you set the **Bend** to 0 on several of the options, you'll get something like this:

[image]

Then you can **Edit > Transform > Skew** and pull down one of the sides until your baseline is straight again.

[image]

Your text will still be editable too, which is nice.

Comment: Thanks for this Vicki (...and for not assuming I had free access to all the other packages, Illustrator etc). I like the way you thought 'out of the box' on this one. Ingenious. In the end, I DID use Illustrator as I wanted uniformity of width in the letters. Photoshop didn't seem cut out for this particular job (...though it really should have this functionality in my opinion). All the best.

Comment: Happy you found a solution that worked!